# Laravel cannot receive (handle) a PHP variable from URL, but on remote only

Tags: php, laravel, variables

I have this extremely simple code snipped in my controller, which always did its job of getting a php varaible from URL:
URL: `wholesaleeventeditions/create?event=36`

```
    $wholesaleevent = Input::get('event');
    if(isset($wholesaleevent)) {
        $event = $wholesaleevent;
    } else {
        $event = null;
    }
```

Now, after I have migrated to new VPS service, Laravel 8 cannot handle the variable. It must be server problem, as my obsolete app build on Laravel 5.8 started to produce similar effect.

#### My environments:

- LOCAL: Windows 10, php 7.4.13 vc 15 TS, Laravel 8 and Laravel 5.8, Apache 2.4.46 VS16 (on newest Laragon 5.0)
- REMOTE: Ubuntu 20.10, Nginx 1.18.0, php 7.4.9
- A Laravel version note: Mu best guess is that it must be something with the Ubuntu 20.10 server config, as the error broke down a separate Laravel 5.8 app of mine. I have no clue though I would blame a quirk in php 7.4.

#### What I tried but to no avail:

- In desperation, I changed `$input = Input::get('event');` to `$input = Input::all();` and then `$event = $wholesaleevent['event'];`. The code works on local, but on remote server it produces `Undefined index: event' error.
- I have disabled SSL protection in my server (and rebooted the server to make sure no caches interfere). In other words: I have changed server to `http` only and accessed it with a separate browser by typing url containing `http` only.

Comment: When server running is https mode, accessing url with http protocol will not get data from url or body. For example: if running https ://example.com, accessing site with http ://example.com?v=1 will not yield v value

Comment: @joHN what are you talking about?

Comment: Pass second parameter to input get and you will recieve that value in case the argument is not present. It will help you debug. Also check if htaccess or vhost is properly configured in case you are using apache

Comment: @joHN
This explanation doesn't work. When looking for a solution I turned off the https access by replacing the Nginx config with an old one and rebooting the server. So I have accessed the site by http, not https. It has not helped.

Comment: @RajeshPaudel "in case you are using apache"
I am using Nginx, as described above.  Thank you for the hint.

Comment: @Peter what do you get with ```$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']``` in server? Does it send you value of query string?

Comment: @RajeshPaudel LOCAL: `36` (as expected) REMOTE: `` (empty)

Comment: @Peter That means the server has not accepted the query parameter. This is not issue with laravel or php. Your webserver is not properly configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an error in both of your Laravels, then it is a NGINX misconfiguration.

This is the most basic config for it, see if you are missing anything:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    index index.php;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    root /var/www/public;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

Also, a small tip for your code: If you are not using the value again (you stored it at `$event`), you can do this to have better code:

```php
$event = Input::get('event');
```

`get` has a second parameter that, by default, is `null`. That parameter will be the default value if `'event'` is not present in the URI. Also, try always to use `Request` (`$request`) and not plain `Input`.

Comment: This was the problem: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`. No `?$query_string`. Thank you.

Comment: Awesome ! Glad I was of help

Answer (score -1):

```
$wholesaleevent = $input = Input::all();
if (isset($wholesaleevent['event'])) {
   $event = $wholesaleevent;
} else {
   $event = null;
}
```

or

```
$wholesaleevent = $input = Input::get('event', false);
if (!empty($wholesaleevent)) {
   $event = $wholesaleevent;
} else {
   $event = null;
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this solution. Doesn't work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: No problem, can you update question expanding this sentence: " Laravel 8 cannot handle the variable" what is the error you're getting on your code, or any unexpected value?

Comment: I added `handle` in the parenthesis, but will not add version number, as I have the same problem in two separate apps: Laravel 8.2 and 5.8.